# Combine commands in ImageMagick

Tags: image, imagemagick, mask

I want to generate image with ImageMagick by this algorithm:

- get image img.png
- add mask to it with mask.png
- put result to another image bg.png
- create result image result.png

I wrote it, but I cant send first result to second command. Can you help me?

**It's working:**

> composite -compose CopyOpacity mask.png img.png masked.png 
>   composite -geometry +5+5 masked.png bg.png result.png

**It's not working:**

> composite -compose CopyOpacity mask.png img.png -geometry +5+5 bg.png
>   result.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

type in your console, with all files in the same directory and being in the same directory:

```
composite -compose CopyOpacity mask.png img.png masked.png && composite -geometry +5+5 masked.png bg.png result.png
```